# Sending mail python webapp2 GAE

Tags: python, email, google-app-engine, sendmail

I initially tried using the `smptlib` library but in order to send an e-mail I need to use `SSL` which costs me with Google App Engine. Other than that, `smtplib` was a perfect solution.

I found a link [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/sendingmail) which explains how to send an email using the GAE API.

However, I can't seem to figure out how one would log in to a gmail account say, in order to send the email.

The purpose of this is to send a verification email to addresses of those who are registering. But in the link it shows how to get the `current_user` and send the email using their credentials. How would I explicitly enter an email, password, and smtp server like I would do with `smtplib` in order to send the email from my desired address.

Thanks for any answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't send from an arbitrary email address. As the [overview docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/) state, you can only send from:

> - The Gmail or Google Apps Account of the user who is currently signed in
> - Any email address of the form anything@appname.appspotmail.com or anything@appalias.appspotmail.com
> - Any email address listed in Email API Authorized Senders found in the App Engine Settings page of the Developers Console

If you are the owner of the email account you want to send from, and it is a GMail account, you can add it to the Email API Authorized Senders list from the App Engine console.

Once that's done, you can just use it as the sender address - you don't need to log into anything.

Comment: Since it's only registration stage, a default gmail user could be signed in by default (i.e - the sender of the email), right? Now that I think of it though, @ppalias.appspotmail.com might be a better approach

Comment: I can't seem to figure out how to use the appspotmail.com email address, though. Any ideas?

Comment: How do you mean, use it? Just set it as the `sender` parameter to EmailMessage.

Comment: I get the error running locally: `INFO     2015-11-19 15:31:04,613 mail_stub.py:306] You are not currently sending out real email.  If you have sendmail installed you can use it by using the server with --enable_sendmail`, and it doesn't work online either

Comment: @GregPeckory, as the message you got clearly mentions, to actually send mail from dev_appserver.py you need to locally install and run sendmail, then run dev_appserver with --enable_sendmail. As for "it doesn't work online", that's far too little info to help -- what do the App Engine logs SAY when you try -- exactly what code are you trying to use -- what error code or message or exception do you receive -- etc, etc. To help us help you, please edit your Q with all the needed details!

Comment: Fixed, had to enable billing with Google App Engine

Comment: I am not able to add other email address in Application setting to send email from other email address :(